# R-squared from conditional mean equation in GARCH models (rugarch package)

Tags: r, r-squared, garch

I was recently asked to report the r-squared statistics together with the estimations of GARCH models with exogenous regressors on the conditional mean equation. However, there is no function to get these statistics automatically using the `rugarch` package.

My question is straightforward:
**Can I use the residuals of the fitted model (`uGARCHfit` class object) to calculate the r-squared and the adjusted r-squared manually or should I use the estimated `sigma` from the fitted model to weight an `lm` object and extract the r-squared from there?**

I did some research but I couldn't find anything in the vignette of the package.

Two exchanges on cross-validated touched the issue:

[How to measure the goodness of fit of a GARCH model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154066/how-to-measure-the-goodness-of-fit-of-a-garch-model/154071#154071)

[How to extract the adjusted r squared from uGARCHfit class data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/342406/how-to-extract-the-adjusted-r-squared-from-ugarchfit-class-data#comment646374_342406)

But they don't provide a definitive answer.

Here is a reproducible example of what I want to do:

````
library(rugarch)
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(fredr)

# Get and clean the data

fredr_set_key("your_key_here") # fredr package requires a key to download the data.

df = map_dfr(c('DEXBZUS', 'DCOILWTICO'), fredr) %>%
  filter(date > '2010-01-01')

df1 = df %>%
  spread(series_id, value) %>%
  set_names('date', 'oil', 'brl') %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-date), list(~ log(.) - lag(log(.)))) %>%
  drop_na

oil = as.matrix(zoo(df1$oil, df1$date))
brl = as.matrix(zoo(df1$brl, df1$date))

# Estimate the model
m1_spec  = ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = 'eGARCH',
                                        garchOrder = c(1,1)), 
                  mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1,0),
                                    external.regressors = oil),
                  distribution.model = 'norm')

m1_fit = ugarchfit(spec = m1_spec, data = brl,
                 solver.control = list(trace = 1))

# Calculate the r-squared statistics
r2 = 1 - (sum(residuals(m1_fit)^2) / sum((brl - mean(brl))^2))
r2a = 1 - ((1 - r2) * (length(brl) - 1) / (length(brl) - 3))
```
````

Comment: My answer in the thread [How to measure the goodness of fit of a GARCH model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154066) that you linked above focuses specifically on fitting the conditional variance, not the remaining aspects of the model (conditional mean, other distributional properties); perhaps I should clarify that there. If you focus on the conditional mean (which is one of the equations that constitute a GARCH model), the usual $R^2$ should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, you can use the residuals of the fitted model (`uGARCHfit` class object) to calculate the $R^2$ and the $R^2_{adj.}$ manually. Note: you need raw residuals, not standardized ones.

You do **not** use the estimated `sigma` from the fitted model to weight an `lm` object and extract the $R^2$ from there; the classical definition of $R^2$ does not involve any weighting.

The last line of your code for calculating $R^2$ appears to be correct.